# Downloading Prisma engines for Node-API for windows getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 59996 Error

Tags: node.js, nestjs, prisma, npx, windows-11

I have been stuck on this problem for a couple of days now and solutions found online are not helpful. I have a nestjs project and installed prisma on. Running the command "`npx prisma generate`", I keep getting the error below

Downloading Prisma engines for Node-API for windows [ ] 0%Error: request to https://binaries.prisma.sh/all_commits/1e7af066ee9cb95cf3a403c78d9aab3e6b04f37a/windows/migration-engine.exe.gz.sha256 failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 59996

From the searches I have seen, some said maybe my laptop is being a proxy server, but I am not. I have disabled proxy, switched to different networks but still getting same issue. I have tried with different versions of NodeJs but still the same.

My current node version is 18.14.2 and npm 9.6.5.
I am using a Windows 11 OS.

I would appreciate some help here.

Thanks everyone

After installing prisma and prisma/client. I created models in my schema file. And then ran the command npx prisma generate. But I keep getting the error above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was using Docker in that project and one time I forgot to run the container. I don't know how, but after running the container and then the `prisma generate` command the error disappeared.

Looks very weird that it helped me, but anyway.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).